# Authorisation Action Filters for WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have an MVC 4 solution which I have been applying authorisation action filters onto various controllers to some additional checks before allow access through to certain controllers.

```
 public class AuthoriseUserViewAccess : FilterAttribute , IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
    }
 }
```

This has been working well with my controllers and actions.

But I also wanted to the same thing with the WEB API controllers I am using in the same solution.

I have tried applying the AuthoriseUserViewAccess attribute to my apicontrollers, but the onAuthorisation method never seems to get invoked.

Should this work with WebAPI Controllers too, or is there another approach for achieving the same thing with WEBAPI.

Comment: Have you tried creating an attribute that inherits from AuthorizationFilterAttribute instead? Also make sure that you are using the filter base class from the correct namespace as the Web API filters come from a different one than the MVC filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this a a test and the OnAuthorization gets called. The attribute is applied on my webapi. Maybe try to inherit from  System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute.

```
    public class CustomAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(
           System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Do other checks
        var ok = false;
        if (!ok)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. probably because I was using the mvc namespace.
What is the difference between implementing the AuthorizeAttribute in your example, and the IAUthorizationFilter in my example? and why would you use one over the other?

Comment: When you inherit from the AuthorizationAttribute you can add your custom validation before or after the base validation. That way you can use the build-in capabilities from the AuthorizationAttribute. If you inherit from IAuthorizationFilter, you have to implement everything from scratch.
It depends of what you want. I personally would inherit from the AuthorizeAttribute and add my custom authorization logic before or after the base OnAuthorization method.